# Tracking search engine referral parameter after referral meta tag

Tags: php, analytics

After searching on google the `keyword+query` parameter were added in the `redirect url` which helped analytic softwares to process the browser `referer` for required data. For years we were able to track the organic traffic and keyword from `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` of a user browser, however few years ago google started using

```
    <meta content="origin" id="mref" name="referrer">
```

This `"referrer" meta-tag` basically tells browser to only add the `origin` in the referrer. That is if a user searches using https://www.google.co.in and reaches my website using that search engine, all I can get from PHP `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is `https://www.google.co.in/`.

My question is how can other website get the searched keywords now **without using Google Analytics** ?

Comment: It can’t. That’s kinda the point of telling browsers which part of the referrer info - if any - the are supposed to pass along.